# Help with component choice for weather proof sensor node

Tags: sensor, component-selection, standard, environmental-sealing

I'm planning on making a wireless weather station with a sensor node and a master to display the sensor data. The sensor node would be placed outside and measure temperature, humidity, and air pressure. As I'm living in Finland, the weather can vary quite much with temperatures between +30 to -30 °C and humidity up to 100%. This brings some challenges to the design and component choices.

The temperature sensor and the pressure sensor can both be placed inside a water-proof enclosure without it affecting the measured values. The humidity sensor would need to be placed outside of the water-proof part of the enclosure, ensuring correct measurements. Therefore, I'm wondering how weather-proof humidity sensors like the [HS3004](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/hs300x-datasheet) are. The datasheets often recommend using the sensor in some temperature range that is above 0°C. Where can I look for components which can handle this environment? Is there some standard I should look for?

Comment: Since humidity sensors deal with water, it's not surprising that one might not work well below water's freezing point.  You may want to search on dew point sensors -- but expect that you may end looking at expensive bits of kit.

Comment: And note that if you know the dew point, you'll need to know the temperature, then do some calculations to get relative humidity -- but those calculations are well known and documented.

Comment: Speak to the supplier about how you can use this in a weather station. Their data sheet says it can be so, they are somewhat obliged to tell you how.